# How to prevent rails from caching Model.all query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand why in development mode, the query is getting cached even after inserting a new record. What I mean is that, after creating a new record, my Model.all doesn't pull that record from the db. I checked with IRB and the record is persisted. Once I restart the server, the new record shows up.

Here is the detail...

- all environment configs are standard ones generated by "rails new app"

First time after starting the server, when i hit the pagecontroller#index, the logs are

```
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Page Load (14.9ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" 
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 167.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.9ms)
```

After creating a page, user gets redirected to index action and the logs are

```
Started GET "/pages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-13 09:40:27 -0400
 Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
 Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 5.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My action

```
def index
  @pages = Page.all
end

def create
  @page = Page.new(params[:page])
  if @page.save
    flash[:notice] = "Page saved Successfully"
    redirect_to :action => "index"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Errors on saving the page"
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

I am pretty new to rails and couldn't find anything in my research of the problem. Can someone help me.

**GEMS**

- actionmailer (3.2.4)
- actionpack (3.2.4)
- activemodel (3.2.4)
- activerecord (3.2.4)
- activeresource (3.2.4)
- activesupport (3.2.4)
- arel (3.0.2)
- bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
- builder (3.0.0)
- bundler (1.1.4)
- ci_reporter (1.7.0)
- coffee-rails (3.2.1)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- hike (1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.0)
- journey (1.0.3)
- json (1.7.3)
- libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-11)
- mail (2.4.4)
- metaclass (0.0.1)
- mime-types (1.18)
- mocha (0.11.4)
- multi_json (1.3.6)
- mynyml-redgreen (0.7.1)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.4.1)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.1)
- rails (3.2.4)
- railties (3.2.4)
- rake (0.9.2.2)
- rdoc (3.12)
- rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
- rvm (1.11.3.3)
- sass (3.1.19)
- sass-rails (3.2.3)
- sprockets (2.1.3)
- sqlite3 (1.3.6)
- term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
- therubyracer (0.10.1)
- thor (0.15.2)
- tilt (1.3.3)
- tinymce-rails (3.5)
- treetop (1.4.10)
- tzinfo (0.3.33)
- uglifier (1.0.3)

Comment: What gems are you using?

Comment: @OscarDelBen - just added the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.2.4 had an issue with caching findall. I suggest you upgrade to a newer version of Rails, as per this question: [Rails 3.2.4 SQL query is caching results on find(:all)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858923/rails-3-2-4-sql-query-is-caching-results-on-findall)